# File path in php

Tags: php

I follow a php course from educator from 2012. Nobody answers there to any question. I put the folder with exercises in C:\wamp\www\educator-php-advance.

The problem is that the images don't show up on any exercises pages. I think the problem is in configuration file. I'm not so advance to php so I don't understand what the professor did here, because he doesn't explain this file.

```
// Get absolute path to 'this' config.php file and replace 
// any backslashes in its path with forward-slashes if needed
$configFilePath = str_replace('\\', '/', __FILE__);

// Get URI of this config.php file relative to the 
// webserver's document root by removing the 
// $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] path from the path to config.php
$configFileURI = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], 
                                '', $configFilePath); 

/**
 * Define the root URI for this version of the web app based on the URI of this config.php file
 */
define('ROOT_URI', str_replace('includes/config.php', '', $configFileURI));

/**
 * Image directory URI constant
 */
define('IMAGE_DIR', ROOT_URI . 'images/');
```

When I look to an image in the browser this is the url:

```
http://localhost/educator-php-advance/web_app/version-5.0/educator-php-advance/web_app/version-5.0/images/1001.jpg
```

So if I change the image path with:

```
    define('IMAGE_DIR', '/educator-php-advance/web_app/version-4.0/images/');
```

I can see the images. 
Can someone please tell me how to change the constants so I can see the images?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question? What is the issue? If the images show with `define('IMAGE_DIR', '/educator-php-ad....` then use that?

Comment: I have to change that constant for every new lesson and in some lesson I have to move the image folder and change again the path.

Comment: Can you try to echo the `IMAGE_DIR` what is the output of it?

Comment: ... I'm not sure I get the issue? Yes, you will have to update the `IMAGE_DIR` constant to make it work in the files where the constant is wrong?

Comment: The output is 1 if I echo IMAGE_DIR.

Comment: Can you explain me what is going on on the ROOT_URI? Why he used those ''. I don't understand what he is replacing.

Comment: Now I get only errors on every page, I mean warnings, after I put your new ROOT_URI : `Warning: include_once`

Comment: Undo that action, and try this: `define("ROOT_URI", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);`

Comment: @Epodax in every lesson the professor doesn't change anything in the config file even he moves to a different folder the config file is the same. But in my case I have to change that path to every new lesson, because every lesson is in a diff folder.

Comment: I get the same errors with the new ROOT_URI, C0dekid.